# Backbone.Layoutmanager error trying to init view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-layout-manager

I'm trying to create a backbone app using Backbone.Layoutmanager.

I'm getting this rather unhelpful error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

I'm starting with an empty html file that I want to render an 'appChrome' layout into.

```
<!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Enrollment Processing</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/layoutmanager/backbone.layoutmanager.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/router.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/views/appChrome.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing to special there.

My app.js is pretty simple too,

```
/* global enrollmentProcessingApp, $ */

window.enrollmentProcessingApp = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Routers: {},
    init: function () {
        'use strict';

        Backbone.Layout.configure({
            manage: true
        });


        var app = new enrollmentProcessingApp.Routers.AppRouter();

        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    enrollmentProcessingApp.init();
});
```

Some of the magic starts to happen in the router

```
/*global enrollmentProcessingApp, Backbone*/

enrollmentProcessingApp.Routers = enrollmentProcessingApp.Routers || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    enrollmentProcessingApp.Routers.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          ''            : 'default_route'
        },

        initialize: function(){
            appChrome = new enrollmentProcessingApp.Views.AppChromeView();

        },

        default_route: function(){
            console.log("default route called");
        }
    });

})();
```

It that line in the initialize function thats throwing the error.

```
appChrome = new enrollmentProcessingApp.Views.AppChromeView();
```

Here's the AppChromeView View. Again very simple.

```
/*global enrollmentProcessingApp, Backbone, JST*/

enrollmentProcessingApp.Views = enrollmentProcessingApp.Views || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    enrollmentProcessingApp.Views.AppChromeView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/appChrome.ejs']

    });

})();
```

As you can see I'm using JST. That template is super simple too.

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did Simon's answer solve the problem for you? It'd be great if we could get this issue resolved.

Comment: @tbranyen I ended up abandoning Layout Manager and going with Marionette so I don't know if that would have answered the question. Should I flag this question somehow?

Comment: i think this issue was fixed in Underscore#1.6.0. I was having the same problem, and upgraded from 1.5.3. to 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by Underscore. Recently they've been breaking backward compatibilities without really caring about users... So error like this one start happening.

Solutions?
- You can revert Underscore to 1.4.3 (or earlier)
- You can use the latest LayoutManager from the `master` Branch or wait for release 0.9.3 (coming soon). (Related issue: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/issues/383)

Comment: i think this issue was fixed in Underscore#1.6.0